# get data from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting this when i implement code 
i dont know how to fix this Im using PHP v 5.3.3

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => banana
            [2] => orange

        )

    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => yellow
            [2] => orange
        )

)
```

But i want output like this

```
"data": [
        {
            "product": "apple",
            "color": "red",
        },
        {
            "product": "banana",
            "color": "yellow",
        },
        {
            "product": "orange",
            "color": "orange",
        },
        ]
```

Please help me if anyone knows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the job:

```php
$products = $your_array['product'];
$colors = $your_array['color'];
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i< count($products) ; $i++) // asserting that the number of products and colors are the same
    array_push($result, (object)[
        'product' => $products[$i],
        'color' => $colors[$i]
    ]);
```

Comment: ok @FaisalSharif try now (changed also the array key for the two arrays from 0 and 1 to product and color as shown in the question)

Comment: what you mean? try to print_r($result) and post what it generate

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => apple
            [color] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => banana
            [color] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => orange
            [color] => 
        )

)

Comment: @FaisalSharif that's strange, can you please also post what's inside $colors before the for loop? (i've deleted the "," after the color entry inside the for, please try with this)

Comment: $colors = $products['color'];

Comment: nono, try copy and paste the code now, and add a print_r($colors) before the for loop and post the output please

Comment: Nothing out put my code  $products['color'] = array('red','yellow','orange');

Comment: no, please, put "print_r($colors)" just before the for loop and post here what it output